# jQuery Mobile with Intel XDK: Endless pageload, when getting cookie content on pageinit

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, cookies, intel-xdk, page-init

Good evening,

I'm programming a mobile-app with intel's xdk. I never had problems until now.

Problem:
I tried to get the content of a cookie when the page is initialised the first time.

```
$("#mainpage").on( "pageinit", function()
  { 
  intel.xdk.cache.getCookie( 'cookie_name' );
  }
```

I only have one index.html with subpages. You can get the error here:

http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/Q3Usv/

**Make sure to check jQuery Mobile 1.2.0 on the left and run**

You should see a endless loading page. That same happens, when I'm trying to get the 
content of my cookie on pageinit. I also tried **pagebeforeshow**, **pagecreate**, **pagebeforecreate**... nearly all events shown on the first image on this site:

http://www.gajotres.net/page-events-order-in-jquery-mobile-version-1-4-update/

**UPDATE IN RESPONSE TO USER SUGGESTIONS:**

- I have also tried binding an event on the document for a specific id `$(document).on( 'pageinit', '#mainpage', function(){} );`
- I do not include jQM or jQ to times

**SOLUTION**

I finally solved it after working nearly a week meticulously on a solution.

**Now for all other's, having the problem out of the XDK:**
Make sure you do not include jQ or jQM a second time and stay tuned which event you have to use.

**Now for all developers, having the same problem I mentioned:** The Intel XDK provides it's own events. One of them is:

`document.addEventListener("intel.xdk.device.ready",onDeviceReady,false);`

This event ensures, that you can use every feature of the Intel XDK. An getting the content of a cookie is one of it. Hope it helps because one week or even more time to struggle with that problem isn't that enjoyable.

Greetings and thank you all for reading and helping

PS: Can be closed!

Comment: in the fiddle, jquery mobile is loaded in head section already. Loading another js library will cause it to malfunction. You need to delegate `pageinit` event to `#mainpage` e.g. `$(document).on("pagecreate", "#mainpage", function () {});` and since you're using jQM 1.4, use `pagecreate` instead.